# How to delete a shape from canvas created by a function in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

New to ktinker and I've met a problem that I can't find a solution to.
My goal is to animate a shape and allow it to move using a function inside a while loop, and the function generates the shape while the while loop deletes and refreshes the canvas.
My code look something like this:

```
def shape():
    global a
    a = screen.create_rectangle(x,100,x+50,200,fill = 'white')

while True:
    shape(x,y)
    x+=10
    screen.update()
    screen.delete(a)
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

the code successfully creates a rectangle and it moves, but the code isn't deleting the rectangles. However, the code works fine and deletes the rectangles if I'm not using a function.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the screen after you delete the shape.

```
def shape():
    global a
    a = screen.create_rectangle(x,100,x+50,200,fill = 'white')

while True:
    shape(x,y)
    x+=10
    screen.update()
    screen.delete(a)
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to animate objects on a `tk.Canvas` is different from `pygame` and other GUI frameworks.

`tk.Canvas` does not require a "blitting" process; the `items` do not need to be deleted, and recreated each frame.
The proper approach is to move existing items, either using the `tk.Canvas.move` method, or the `tk.Canvas.coord` method. The first moves the item by a provided `δx` and `δy`, whereas the second re-positions the item to the new coordinates passed to it.

Here is an example with `tk.Canvas.move`:

```
import tkinter as tk


def shape(x):
    return screen.create_rectangle(x, 100, x+50 , 200, fill='white')


def animate(rect, dx=0, dy=0):
    screen.move(rect, dx, dy)
    screen.after(100, animate, rect, dx)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    screen = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg='cyan')
    screen.pack()

    rect = shape(50)
    animate(rect, dx=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Notice that we make use of the `tk.mainloop` provided by the framework, instead of a clumsy `while True` loop. The `tk.after` method is the correct approach to call a function (here `animate`) at regular intervals.
We also avoid the use of `time.sleep` which always results to problems and blocking the GUI.